# Event triggered on leaving the page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger an event when the user leaves the page, meaning changing the tab, etc. This is what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
                alert('Youre trying to leave this page');
            });

            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert('test');
            });
        </script>
        <title>Bounce catcher</title>       
    </head>
    <body>
        hdjkfhdskjfhdskhfds
    </body>
</html>
```

But it doesn't work. The "test" alert appears normally, but the other alert on beforeunload event doesn't work, appear, nothing. Neither on changing the tab, nor on closing it.

I am using chrome on osx, what's wrong? Console doesn't show anything either. Changing the event to simply "unload" also doesn't work. Placing the window function inside document block doesn't work.

Comment: You cannot, just check the DOC for `beforeunload` event. You should return a string but this is browser implementation's dependant

Comment: So how can I do this?

Comment: `return 'Youre trying to leave this page';` instead of `alert()` AFAIK, FF (version?) don't allow custom string

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/unload/

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I do know that it won't work sometimes. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @khernik Not on any modern browsers. You can **just** return a string to show a confirm dialog box (which is modal, blocking any other executing script). You could play with browser history API or other silly hack to just bore your users but don't...

Comment: @khernik Could you post your code in Fiddler, Because I think all the answers below should work , Your alert will not work because you can not assign an alert to return value property of window event, It only accepts string we are using window event by returning a message only.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
        return 'Youre trying to leave this page';
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        alert('test');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace alert with return in your function, remember that `beforeunload`  return is must in this function for this function to work

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
                return 'Youre trying to leave this page';
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Youre trying to leave this page';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3kvAC/2619/